# Tableau - detect duplicates on a rolling window

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a report which reports distinct number of email addresses seen in an event log across a 7 day moving windows. Have easily been done this using group by and COUNTD but have not been able to figure out how to do a 7 day moving window deduping.

Eg: Someone placed an event on 15 Dec and another on 17 Dec. Becuase I am grouping by week and doing a COUNTD on email, the dupe gets detected. However, if someone placed an event on the 13th and another on the 14th, this is not counted as a duplicate because a new group starts on the 14th. I get 1 event each in the 2 groups.

How can I detect dupes across groups/partitions? Please help. My sample data is below

```
Field1  Field2
sample@email.com    13-Dec-15
sample2@email.com   14-Dec-15
sample@email.com    15-Dec-15
sample3@email.com   15-Dec-15
sample3@email.com   16-Dec-15
```

My current output is

```
Period,NumDistinctEmails
7Dec - 13Dec, 1
14Dec - 20Dec, 3
```

The output i want (because sample@email is duplicate across tables)

```
Period,NumDistinctEmails
7Dec - 13Dec, 1
14Dec - 20Dec, 2
```

Comment: What else you tried for this ? looks interesting but not sure if its valid.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible in pure Tableau.
However, I can suggest you to add new column `is_unique`: which is equal 1 if it was the first time email occured in  the log, otherwise set it to 0. After theat you can easily calculate what you want.
This column you can add with custom_sql or with some preprocessing

Comment: How are you grouping your 7 days ? Either you can create `week` then `COUNTD` on it. Or `CREATE GROUP` in Tableau itself for selected Dates. Grouping with `WINDOW_CALCS` will not help as data is already inside the viz . You have to Group Before hand.